# How can I set dot as decimal separator in GridView?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, culture

I have some `BoundField`s that are bonded to double values. If I enable editing on the `GridView` I get the following example:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

I want that in edit mode the decimal separator be "." instead of "," but I can't get it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set in the Page directive the Culture to "en-US" and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

try it :

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Price"
                HeaderText="Price"
                SortExpression="Price"
                DataFormatString="{0:F3}" />
```

Comment: This just displays numeric values in fixed format and specify the number of decimal places. It doesn't replaces the "," to ".".

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio set Language in Tools - Options - International Settings to "Same as Microsoft Windows". If your Windows' Regional settings are set correctly, your problem should be solved.